# which kind of singularity has $f(z) = \frac{1}{z} + e^{\frac{1}{z}}$?

Tags: complex-analysis

I wondering which kind of sigularity point has $f(z) = \frac{1}{z} + e^{\frac{1}{z}}$.

I know that $e^{\frac{1}{z}}$ has essential singularity in 0, and $1/z$ has a pole in same point, but I can't find an easy way to found out $f$'s singularity kind in 0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the principal part of the Laurent series at $z= 0$ has infinitely many (non-zero) members, the singularity is essential.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible answer to my question:

The fact that the meromorphic functions are field, and $\frac{1}{z}$ meromorphic,
implies:

$\frac{1}{z} + e^{\frac{1}{z}}$ meromorphic $\Rightarrow ((\frac{1}{z} + e^{\frac{1}{z}}) - \frac{1}{z})$ meromorphic $\Rightarrow e^{\frac{1}{z}}$ meromorphic, contradiction.